# echoing the existing session username php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'db.login.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['users']) != "") {
    header("Location: profile.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    if ($row['password'] == md5($upass)) {
        $_SESSION['users'] = $row['id'];
        header("Location: profile.php");
    } else {
        $err = "<p style='color: red'>Wrong Username or Password</p>";
        ?>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

method i am trying but it doesn't seem to display anything

```
<?= $_SESSION['username'] ?>">
```

i am basically looking at echoing the username logged into the session

Comment: Are you shure it exists? Try `var_dump($_SESSION['username'])` instead.

Comment: Where are you trying it to print ?

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['users'])!="")` is a false positive method.

Comment: you should not use this code in a live environment.

Comment: Too late @Fred -ii-  looks like its live lol. md5.  Seriously??

Comment: @Akintunde May the Lord have pity on their souls. Oh wait, I think that's a Maritime expression.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'db.login.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['users']) && $_SESSION['users'] != "")
{
    header("Location: profile.php");
    exit();

}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['password'] == md5($upass))
    {
        $_SESSION['users'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];


        header("Location: profile.php");
    }
    else
    {
            $err = "<p style='color: red'>Wrong Username or Password</p>";
        ?>

        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

you did not define `$_SESSION['username']` anywhere.

Comment: you need to better explain the answer, it's also still unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

you fill session in

```
$_SESSION['users']
```

but echo

```
$_SESSION['username']
```